# Python class is created when module is imported

Tags: python

I have a Python module that is written like so.

```
SomeClasses.py
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print "Hi! A is instantiated!"

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print "Hi! B is instantiated!"


a = A()
```

When the file is imported, class A is automatically instantiated.

```
>>> import a
Hi! A is instantiated!
```

Now, most of the time, this is exactly the behavior I want.  However, sometimes I do not want an entire class to be instantly created during the import because of the overhead.  I did consider creating an init() function.

```
>>> import SomeClasses
>>> SomeClasses.init()
Hi! A is instantiated!
```

However, this would break most of the preexisting code.  I want to avoid rewriting a lot of the existing code base.  Can anyone suggest a way to tell the module upon import to not create the class?

Btw, I am running Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: Are you looking for `if __name__ == '__main__':`? A description can be found in this answer :http://stackoverflow.com/a/419986/1388292

Comment: It doesn't look like this is a case for a `__name__ == '__main__'` check, considering that the questioner usually wants the initialization to happen on a regular import.

Comment: Probably not. Just checking...

Comment: You're not "creating the class" you're creating an instance. The answer to your question depends on why you create the instance, `a = A()` inside the module in the first place. Is `A` a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)? Why does `A.__init__` have so much overhead?

Comment: Yes, A is a singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refactor `SomeClasses` and move most of it into another module:

```
# SomeClasses.py

# One of the few legitimate uses of import * outside of an interactive session.
from _SomeClasses import *
a = A()

# _SomeClasses.py
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Hi! A is instantiated!"

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Hi! B is instantiated!"
```

Then if you don't want the expensive initialization of `a`, you import `_SomeClasses` and use that module. The other code that relies on `a` existing will import `SomeClasses` and get the automatically-created `a` instance.